# Obsidian Scheduler set up issue for implementing jobs

Tags: java, tomcat, scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling

I am new to Obsidian Scheduler and trying to get started by setting up the environment.

- I have downloaded Obsidian from : http://obsidianscheduler.com/download/
  and completed the installation successfully. I am Using MySQL database and Tomcat 7.
- Copied the obsidan.war from the installation folder of Obsidian into the webapps folder of tomcat and by starting the server I am able to
  access **localhost:8080/obsidian/** and perform various actions like add jobs,view job
  history etc

Now further , I would like to set up a project in Eclipse and implement my own job and deploy the same onto the server.

I have been trying to refer : http://obsidianscheduler.com/wiki/Implementing_Jobs#Classpath_for_Building_and_Deploying , but still not getting clarity on what needs to be done as I am new to software development.

I tried creating a new java project and adding the external jars from /standalone directory of the installation. I am not sure how to proceed further.I have looked into docs provided on the obsidian website.

It would be extremely helpful if someone could share the steps on how do i achieve this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://obsidianscheduler.com/wiki/Getting_Started#Embedded_Scheduler

That is the section you need to be looking at. This will embed the scheduler into your application and you can run the Obsidian Web app on a separate instance.